# Chef infra how to delete user?

Tags: chef-infra

I need a recet for the CHEF. How to delete users? So that when checking the VM list, there are no users. For example:

```
cat /etc/group|grep john.deer
john.deer:x:1043:
```

To create new users, we use gitlab
master/chef01-cookbooks/bags/users
username.json

Recipe in:
chef01-cookbooks/cookbooks/users/recipes/create_cto.rb

```
#service 'nslcd' do
# action [ :stop ]
#end

unless node['platform'] == 'windows'

users_manage 'fgp' do
  group_id 9999
  action [:create, :remove]
  data_bag 'users'
end

#users_manage 'dev' do
# group_id 500
# action [:create, :remove]
# data_bag 'users'
#end
```

How to add a recipe that will remove unnecessary users. Please describe in more detail, because I have known the chef recently.

Now in users who are not needed in
chef01-cookbooks/-/tree/master/bags/users username.json

```
{
  "id": "user.name",
  "username": "john.deer",
  "comment": "xxccc",
  "shell":"/dev/null",
  "groups": [
    "fgp"
  ],
  "action":"remove",
  "ssh_keys": [
    "disable"
  ]
}
```

Now in users who are not needed in
chef01-cookbooks/-/tree/master/bags/users username.json

after the chef-client starts, the users are in place, they are not deleted. the list of VMs is about 500 pieces

working users (they are needed)

```
{
   "id": "johndo",
   "username": "johndo",
   "comment": "john",
   "groups": [
     "fgp"
   ],
   "ssh_keys": [
     "ssh-rsa AAAAB... .... ...t"
   ]
}
```

after executing chef-client:

```
`* group[john.deer] action create (skipped due to only_if)
* linux_user[john.deer] action create (up to date)
* directory[/home/john.deer/.ssh] action create (up to date)
* template[/home/john.deer/.ssh/authorized_keys] action create (up 
to date)`

 `{
  "id": "john.deer",
  "username": "john.deer",
  "comment": "jd",
  "shell":"/dev/null",
  "groups": [
  "fgp"
 ],
 "action":"remove",
 "ssh_keys": [
 "disable"
 ]
```

}`

need to create a new recipe in
chef01-cookbooks/cookbooks/users/recipes/
and the recipe will only delete?
for example, you need to delete only 10 users, do not touch the rest

```
`#service 'nslcd' do
# action [ :stop ]
#end

unless node['platform'] == 'windows'

users_manage 'fgp' do
group_id 9999
action [:remove]
data_bag 'users'
```

end

Comment: Seems you will need to get familiar with using [data bags](https://docs.chef.io/data_bags/). Then Chef resource will have to conditionally add or remove user based on the `"action"` defined in JSON. At this point its hard to answer as this needs more focus. Also, please edit the question and post relevant code/output instead of comment.

Comment: @seshadri_c

need to create a new recipe in chef-cookbooks/cookbooks/users/recipes/ and the recipe will only delete? for example, you need to delete only 10 users, do not touch the rest?

Answer (score 0):

The `data_bag` property is deprecated for the `users_manage` resource. You might have noticed a warning such as below during `chef-client` run:

```
Deprecated features used!
  The data_bag property has been deprecated, please see upgrading.md for more information. The property will be removed in the next major release. at 1 location:
```

The alternative [suggested](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/users) is to read the data bag contents into a variable and use it with the `users` property.

```rb
users_from_databag = search('users', '*:*')

users_manage 'fgp' do
  group_id 9999
  action [:create, :remove]
  users users_from_databag
end
```

I tried this method with version 8.1.4 of the cookbook, and it removed the users marked with `"action": "remove"`.

Another option that can be used as one-time is, to prepare a list of users to be deleted, and remove them. Example:

```rb
%w(
  user1
  user2
  # and so on
).each do |u|
  user u do
    action :remove
  end
end
```